# Микросервисы (Python, FastApi) не могут взаимодействовать при упаковке в контейнеры docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, fastapi, микросервисы

Стек: python, fastapi, httpx, docker, rest api.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в следующем:
Сделал 3 сервиса. Все 3 сервиса работают при запуске их через терминал. При упаковке в Docker и запуске через docker-compose сервисы не могут общаться друг с другом.

Каждый контейнер пингует все контейнеры по именам контейнеров.

При запуске через терминал сервисы обращаются друг к другу через localhost. При запуске в docker localhost заменяется на имя необходимого контейнера, указанное в docker-compose.yml.

При подключении через терминал к работающим контейнерам проверил правильно ли установлена переменная среды **DOCKER_FLAG** и правильно ли отрабатывает участок кода с её интерпретацией - работает правильно. В контейнере переменная **DOCKER** имеет значение **True**.

**Что попробовал сделать:**

Также пробовал заменять имя контейнера в адресе **http://loader:8001/loader** на **http://host.docker.internal:8001/converter** - результат не получил.

Переустановка Docker тоже не помогла.

Пробовал библиотеку **requests** и синхронный режим. Результат такой же. Работает при запуске сервисов из терминала, но не работает при разворачивании в контейнерах.

Пробовал делать отдельную сеть **backend** в **docker-compose.yml** и связывать все 3 контейнера в неё - не помогло.

Пробовал открывать порты только для контейнера **loader 8000:8000** и не открывать портов для сервисов **converter** и **saver** - не помогло.

Кратко приведу примеры файлов.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  loader:
    container_name: loader
    build: loader/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - saver
      - converter

  converter:
    container_name: converter
    build: converter/app
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"

  saver:
    container_name: saver
    build: saver/app
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    volumes:
      - ./saver/app/saved_files:/app/saved_files
```

**Dockerfile для сервиса loader**

```
FROM fnndsc/python-poetry

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping

ENV DOCKER_FLAG=1

RUN poetry self update

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

COPY poetry.lock ./
COPY pyproject.toml ./

RUN poetry install

COPY __init__.py ./
COPY loader.py ./

CMD ["uvicorn", "loader:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--log-level", "debug", "--reload"]
```

**Некоторые участки кода из сервиса loader.py**

**Для чтения переменной среды**

```
DOCKER = False
if os.environ.get("DOCKER_FLAG", default=False):
    DOCKER = True
```

**Простейшая точка для GET запроса, где определяется по какому URL делать обращение**

```
@app.get("/")
def main():
    if DOCKER:
        url = r"http://loader:8000/"
    else:
        url = r"http://localhost:8000/"
    content = f'<body>' \
        f'<form action={url} enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' \
        f'<input name="file" type="file">' \
        f'<input type="submit">' \
        f'</form>' \
        f'</body>'
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
```

**Простейшая точка для POST запроса**

```
@app.post("/")
async def download_file(file: UploadFile):
    if not file.filename.endswith(".csv"):
        return {"error": "File must be CSV"}

    if DOCKER:
        url = r"http://converter:8001/converter"
    else:
        url = r"http://localhost:8001/converter"

    file_to_request = {"file": (file.filename, file.file, file.content_type)}

    response = await app.session.post(url=url, files=file_to_request)

    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
        return JSONResponse(response.json())
```

---

Также приведу пример одного из запусков, где указана конфигурация сети и один GET запрос. Обратите внимание на IP адрес для GET запроса. Он соответствует **Gateway**, а не контейнеру **loader**.

**Вывод из *docker network inspect worktest_default***

```
[
    {
        "Name": "worktest_default",
        "Id": "fa8a4a25bbdcce12feb2e737331c8a9c7dbf855393a8ee14be19edc8765ef11e",
        "Created": "2023-10-04T15:08:12.981556631+07:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "227178c407bd3bfa9b8a3efb7a0b19252a065b4607e7b730d6fa68ef1863fa84": {
                "Name": "loader",
                "EndpointID": "707c1e0e4bc903927cc114050687ab1328ab4f75554e3b5f562eb00554e095f1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d7cdd4239b51c9f08ff2e4deb4ab4edf5f2fc0ab00ce1358376923e18d3a63ad": {
                "Name": "converter",
                "EndpointID": "cfa47bbae2a9e6a2023280393dcc5ebbedf7fb2c295a9cb5a5873c9df0447415",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e630abe88f218834f693c1858811fa44db54aa1e1f5694c04fa794737aa2084d": {
                "Name": "saver",
                "EndpointID": "cbf8cb45344546e43db8f2663f0d6fd10bdf5292253205eba21b787a3daeb1e2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "worktest",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    }
]
```

**Логи docker при обновлении страницы на *localhost:8000/* - это обращение к сервису *loader***

```
loader | INFO:  172.19.0.1:58386 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Однако при отправлении файла методом POST получаю следующую информацию об ошибке в браузере:

> Не удается получить доступ к сайту
> Проверьте, нет ли опечаток в имени хоста loader.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

А информации о POST запросе в логах нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loader:8000...` и прочие адреса доступны только внутри `docker` сети (`worktest_default`). Поэтому когда вы формируете html страницу с формой для отправки файла в `loader` и отдаете клиенту, то в `action={url}` находится `http://loader:8000`, который не доступен с хоста когда вы делаете запрос через браузер.

Если у вас запрос на тот же сервис с которого пришла страница (т.е. `loader` отдал страницу и ему же мы отправляем ответ через форму), то вы можете использовать относительные адреса, вместо абсолютных, например `action=/`, тогда браузер будет автоматически правильно вычислять нужный адрес. В вашем случае этого должно быть достаточно.

Если вы хотите получать html форму из одного сервиса, а отправлять в другой, нарпимер `loader` отдает форму, а на `converter` отправляется запрос из браузера. То в таком случае правильный адрес, который `loader` должен отдавать в форме передают через конфигурацию, например переменные окружения.

Comment: Благодарю, это сработало.
Объясните пожалуйста про передачу формы через конфигурацию.
Я сделал переменную среды, которая указывает на то, что сценарий запускается в контейнере. И в зависимости от этого сценарий сам принимает решение какую ссылку выбрать.
Это то, о чём вы говорили?

Comment: @Dezox не совсем, в loader добавить `CONVERTER_URL` и в `form action={CONVERTER_URL}/...`, а `CONVERTER_URL` правильный адрес, который доступен из внешней сети и у вас это всегда будет localhost, таже в докере